# How can I select from a collection with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IList collection called menuItems.

Here's my MenuItem class:

```
   public class MenuItem
    {
        public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
        public string RowKey { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I select the Order from this collection when `PartitionKey = "00"` and `RowKey = "20"`. Can I use LINQ for this?

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = menuItemsCollection
    .Where(mnu=>mnu.RowKey=="20" && mnu.PartitionKey=="00")
    .Select(mnu=>mnu.Order);
```

The result of this query will be an `IEnumerable<string>`, since that's what the `Order` field is.

The `Where()` filters the collection down to the items you want. The `Select()` chooses what is 'returned'. You could choose to compose a completely different object, for example:

```
var result = menuItemsCollection
    .Where(mnu=>mnu.RowKey=="20" && mnu.PartitionKey=="00")
    .Select(mnu=>
        new SomeOtherClass{Order=mnu.Order, RowKey=mnu.RowKey, RunOn=DateTime.Now});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using classes in the System.Linq namespace you can do the following:

```
var orders = menuItems
    .Where(menuItem=>menuItem.PartitionKey=="00" && menuItem.RowKey=="20")
    .Select(menuItem=> menuItem.Order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must using "System.Linq" and you will found a group of extensions for your menuitem list.

```
IList<MenuItem> list = ...
var orders = list.Where(item=>item.PartitionKey=="00" && item.RowKey=="20").Select(item => item.Order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var orders = from item in menuItems  
where item.PartitionKey == "00" && item.RowKey == "20"  
select new { Order = item.Order};
```

Try looking at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b to learn the LINQ basics. It's a very clear set of examples